# Changing position of the child in table - CSS

Tags: html, css

Imagine that I have `<table>`, then I want to change the position of the image and the text in the child "`nth-child`" of the table. Is it possible to do that? Please help me out of this problem thanks.

here's the code of the table

```
<table id="tbl-inquiry">
  <tr>
    <td><img class="table-img"src="images/2.jpg"></td>
    <td><h5 class="table-title">sample</h5>
    <p class="table-description">sample text.</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="table-img"src="images/2.jpg"></td>
    <td><h5 class="table-title">sample</h5>
    <p class="table-description">sample text.</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

sample output
[image]

Comment: `<table>` elements can't be manipulated to this extent in CSS, but you could achieve the same effect by alternating the order of your `<td>` elements on every row in your HTML.

Comment: use css grid. it will remove all the pain you might experience with tables some day.

Comment: thankyouuuuuuu!! @JonUleis

Comment: thankyouuU!! @GottZ

Comment: you should thank the community. css grid is quite new in all browsers and removes all the pain we had with such ideas in the past. really a life saver.

Comment: oh and don't confuse it with flex box. totally different approach to a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with a table, however it's super easy if you use CSS Grid instead.

Here is a super solid resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: but the problem is, the data's are from my database, how can be possible to do that grid?

Comment: that should be part of a new question.

Comment: @pacificskybeachresort, you just need to query the database and run a for each loop.